# Applications for listening to streaming radio

Tags: music, internet, streaming, radio

Is there a decent app just for listening to the internet radio streams? 
So I can enter the stream URL (MP3, AAC) and tune in.

I can see apps like TuneIn or iHeartRadio, but those are tailored for the specific companies services & stations, and I don't want to depend on that. They also seem to be more podcast-oriented.

Then there are apps like Pandora, Spotify, Grooveshark, MixRadio etc., but those look like some huge media libraries that provide info on the artists & bands, allow you to compile your own playlists, use suggestions etc. I think that's actually a misuse of the word "radio" but who cares anyway.

I am looking for something like [SPB Radio for Windows Mobile](http://archive.news.softpedia.com/news/New-SPB-Radio-Application-for-Windows-Mobile-Available-118015.shtml) - it's a very simple program that allows me to enter the stream URL and listen to it directly, it is abstracted from the features I've listed above. I don't need the stations directory, artist's photos or anything; just being able to listen *to the streams I specifically want to listen to* would be fine. Bad news is that the program does not support the AAC streams which are becoming more and more popular nowadays.

Tried to search on the Internet but couldn't find anything relevant.

I'm particularly looking for an app that:

- would *not* require me to sign in or have an account anywhere (except for the marketplace in case the app is not free);
- would *not* require me to grant permissions to my files, personal data or address book etc (ridiculous yet common nowadays), and;
- would *not* track whatever I'm doing or listening to and/or upload any data to the developers servers.

I don't have a WP device yet but I'm considering getting one right now. I guess the default music app should be enough but I've tried the default (Xbox?) Music app on my Windows 8 computer and it wasn't able to play the AAC stream I wanted, although the stream is valid and a 3rd party media player I'm using plays it just fine.

Please advise.